# Mounting afp share via fstab crashes boot boot process but works after boot

Tags: mount, systemd, fstab, automounting

I just migrated my NFS shares to AFP shares.

It looks like it works like it should so I added the records to my fstab:

```
afpfs#afp://username:password@192.168.1.100/Transfer /home/andy/NAS/Transfer fuse user=andy,group=fuse 0 0
```

When the system is running, I can mount the shares via sudo mount -all

```
[andy@archStd01 ~]$ sudo mount -all
Unknown option exec, skipping
Unknown option suid, skipping
Unknown option dev, skipping
Unknown option dev, skipping
Unknown option suid, skipping
The afpfs daemon does not appear to be running for uid 1000, let me start it for you
Mounting 192.168.1.100 from Transfer on /home/andy/NAS/Transfer
Mounting of volume Transfer of server DiskStation01 succeeded.
```

btw anyone knews this is:

```
Unknown option suid, skipping
Unknown option dev, skipping
Unknown option dev, skipping
Unknown option suid, skipping
```

something that I should worry about?

but when I reboot the system it crashes during the booting process while mounting the shares:
[image]

Text from "screenshot":

```
    ● home-andy-NAS-Transfer.mount - /home/andy/NAS/Transfer
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; generated; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-07-30 20:21:18 CEST; 26s ago
    Where: /home/andy/NAS/Transfer
     What: afpfs#afp://username:password@192.168.1.100/Transfer
     Docs: man:fstab(5)
           man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
  Process: 525 ExecMount=/usr/bin/mount afpfs#afp://username:password@192.168.1.100/Transfer /home/andy/NAS/Transfer -t fuse -o user=andy,group=fuse (code=exited, status=2)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/home-andy-NAS-Transfer.mount

Jul 30 20:21:17 archStd01 systemd[1]: Mounting /home/andy/NAS/Transfer...
Jul 30 20:21:17 archStd01 [529]: Starting up AFPFS version 0.8.1
Jul 30 20:21:18 archStd01 systemd[1]: home-andy-NAS-Transfer.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=2
Jul 30 20:21:18 archStd01 systemd[1]: Failed to mount /home/andy/NAS/Transfer.
Jul 30 20:21:18 archStd01 systemd[1]: home-andy-NAS-Transfer.mount: Unit entered failed state.
```

has anyone an idea what might went wrong?

Im on ArchLinux and use community/afpfs-ng 0.8.1-10

Logfiles:
dmesg: https://ghostbin.com/paste/9jgg8
journalctl -r: https://ghostbin.com/paste/zfwdg

Comment: Can you add the output of `dmesg` and show the contents of `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: [No need for screenshots.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/)  Just redirect the output of `systemctl status` to a file.  Make sure that `systemctl` does not truncate the lines, because what has been chopped off the end of that output is important.  The "unknown option" stuff is really a separate question; and we do one question per question here.

Comment: I just added dmesg and journalctl -r to my op.
No syslog because im on systemd.

Comment: @jdeBP I added the plaintext u needed. Thanks.

Comment: About the `Unknown option`, my guess is that the mount tool reading fstab does have some defaults options (even when not using the option defaults), such as dev and suid. These options does not exist for AFPFS tool, so it skip these. -> Nothing to worry about.